# Example of SOAP request authenticated with WS-UsernameToken

Tags: web-services, soap, ws-security, digest, usernametoken

I'm trying to authenticate a SOAP request using WS-UsernameToken spec, but the target device is always denying access. My non-working request looks like this. (The password I'm trying to hash is `system`.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <Header>
  <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <UsernameToken>
      <Username>root</Username>
      <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">EVpXS/7yc/vDo+ZyIg+cc0fWdMA=</Password>
      <Nonce>tKUH8ab3Rokm4t6IAlgcdg9yaEw=</Nonce>
      <Created xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2010-08-10T10:52:42Z</Created>
    </UsernameToken>
  </Security>
 </Header>
  <Body>
    <SomeRequest xmlns="http://example.ns.com/foo/bar" />
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

What I'm looking for is a similar request example, but with authentication token that actually works. For example if you have gSOAP application that uses these token, and can generate a request and post the result here, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The core thing is to define prefixes for namespaces and use them to fortify each and every tag - you are mixing 3 namespaces and that just doesn't fly by trying to hack defaults. It's also good to use exactly the prefixes used in the [standard do](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/16782/wss-v1.1-spec-os-UsernameTokenProfile.pdf)c - just in case that the other side get a little sloppy.

Last but not least, it's much better to use default types for fields whenever you can - so for password you have to list the type, for the Nonce it's already Base64.

Make sure that you check that the generated token is correct before you send it via XML and don't forget that the content of wsse:Password is Base64( SHA-1 (nonce + created + password) ) and date-time in wsu:Created can easily mess you up. So once you fix prefixes and namespaces and verify that yout SHA-1 work fine without XML (just imagine you are validating the request and do the server side of SHA-1 calculation) you can also do a truial wihtout Created and even without Nonce. Oh and Nonce can have different encodings so if you really want to force another encoding you'll have to look further into wsu namespace.

```
<S11:Envelope xmlns:S11="..." xmlns:wsse="..." xmlns:wsu= "...">
  <S11:Header>
  ...
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>NNK</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="...#PasswordDigest">weYI3nXd8LjMNVksCKFV8t3rgHh3Rw==</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>WScqanjCEAC4mQoBE07sAQ==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2003-07-16T01:24:32</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  ...
  </S11:Header>
...
</S11:Envelope>
```

Comment: pst, S12 namespace is not defined: <S12:Envelop xmlns:S11="..." should be <S11:Envelop or xmlns:S12="..."  nice answer thought, thanks

Comment: @ZXX - Could you please guide how to disable security ?

Answer (score 9):

The [Hash Password Support and Token Assertion Parameters in Metro 1.2](http://blogs.oracle.com/ashutosh/entry/hash_password_support_and_token) explains very nicely what a  UsernameToken with Digest Password looks like:

> #### Digest Password Support
>
> The [**WSS 1.1 Username Token
>   Profile**](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/16782/wss-v1.1-spec-os-UsernameTokenProfile.pdf) allows digest passwords to
>   be sent in a `wsse:UsernameToken` of a
>   SOAP message. Two more optional
>   elements are included in the
>   `wsse:UsernameToken` in this case:
>   `wsse:Nonce` and `wsse:Created`. A
>   nonce is a random value that the
>   sender creates to include in each
>   UsernameToken that it sends. A
>   creation time is added to combine
>   nonces to a "freshness" time period.
>   The Password Digest in this case is
>   calculated as:
>
> ```
> Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + password ) )
> ```
>
> This is how a UsernameToken with
>   Digest Password looks like:
>
> ```
> <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="uuid_faf0159a-6b13-4139-a6da-cb7b4100c10c">
>    <wsse:Username>Alice</wsse:Username>
>    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">6S3P2EWNP3lQf+9VC3emNoT57oQ=</wsse:Password>
>    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">YF6j8V/CAqi+1nRsGLRbuZhi</wsse:Nonce>
>    <wsu:Created>2008-04-28T10:02:11Z</wsu:Created>
> </wsse:UsernameToken>
> ```

Comment: What is wsu:Id="uuid_faf0159a-6b13-4139-a6da-cb7b4100c10c" in this?

Comment: the link is broken unfortunately :(

Comment: wsse:Created or wsu:Created? What is the difference?

Answer (score 4):

Check this one (Password should be password):

```
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-6138db82-5a4c-4bf7-915f-af7a10d9ae96">
  <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
  <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">CBb7a2itQDgxVkqYnFtggUxtuqk=</wsse:Password>
  <wsse:Nonce>5ABcqPZWb6ImI2E6tob8MQ==</wsse:Nonce>
  <wsu:Created>2010-06-08T07:26:50Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this post ([Secure Metro JAX-WS UsernameToken Web Service with Signature, Encryption and TLS (SSL)](http://java.globinch.com/enterprise-java/web-services/jax-ws/secure-metro-jax-ws-usernametoken-web-service-signature-encryption/)) provides more insight. As they mentioned "Remember, unless password text or digested password is sent on a secured channel or the token is encrypted, neither password digest nor cleartext password offers no real additional security. "